# java arraylist add null pointer exception

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Human {
private int age;
private float height;
private float weight;
private String name = new String();

public Human() {
}

public Human(String name, int age, float height, float weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public Human(Human human) {
    this.name = human.getName();
    this.age = human.getAge();
    this.height = human.getHeight();
    this.weight = human.getWeight();
}

public static void writeFile(Human human, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    output.write((human.getName() + "\n").getBytes());
    output.write((human.getAge() + "\n").getBytes());
    output.write((human.getHeight() + "\n").getBytes());
    output.write((human.getWeight() + "\n").getBytes());
}

public static Human readFile(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    int temp;
    String file = "";
    String[] fileArray;

    file += (char) input.read();
    while ((temp = input.read()) != -1) {
        file += (char) temp;
    }

    fileArray = file.split("\n", 0);

    Human madeHuman = new Human(fileArray[0], Integer.parseInt(fileArray[1]), Float.parseFloat(fileArray[2]), Float.parseFloat(fileArray[3]));

    return madeHuman;
}

public static void writeArrayListInFile(ArrayList<Human> humans, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < humans.size(); i++) {
        output.write((humans.get(i).getName() + "\n").getBytes());
        output.write((humans.get(i).getAge() + "\n").getBytes());
        output.write((humans.get(i).getHeight() + "\n").getBytes());
        output.write((humans.get(i).getWeight() + "\n").getBytes());
        output.write('#');
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Human> readArrayListFromFile(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    int temp = ' ';
    String file = "";
    String[] fileArray1;
    String[][] fileArray2 = new String[10][];
    ArrayList<Human> madeHumanArrayList = new ArrayList<Human>();

    file += (char) input.read();
    while ((temp = input.read()) != -1) {
        file += (char) temp;
    }

    fileArray1 = file.split("#", 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileArray1.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            fileArray2[i] = fileArray1[i].split("\n", 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileArray2.length; i++)
        madeHumanArrayList.add(new Human(fileArray2[i][0], Integer.parseInt(fileArray2[i][1]), Float.parseFloat(fileArray2[i][2]), Float.parseFloat(fileArray2[i][3])));//null pointer exception

    return madeHumanArrayList;
}
```

}

---

Although I've had initialized my arraylist, it gives me nullpointer exception. I'm a biginner in java so I will appreciate any simple help.

Comment: sorry for repeated sentence:$

Comment: On what line is your exception?

Comment: Please verify what you are posting before submitting to avoid the above repetitive jumble.

Comment: In case of raising a question which has exceptions, it is always a good idea to provide a stack trace and show the line in the code which has the error. This will help the users to help you better.

Comment: @Benjy Kessler as I have put comment, befor last line, when I add object to arraylist

Comment: My guess is that the error occurs in method `writeArrayListInFile` due to a bug in code which call this, which you haven't included.  I suggest you step through your code in your debugger so you can see why the value is `null`.  My guess is you are discarding the value returned by `readArrayListFromFile`

Comment: That line is very long. Split it up to see exactly which call is generating the exception.

Comment: @ Benjy Kessler tnx, It is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have put comment, befor last line, when I add object to arraylist

You code reads

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileArray1.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        fileArray2[i] = fileArray1[i].split("\n", 0);
```

This means you only set values in `fileArray2` up to an index of `fileArray1.length`

But you read values in this array up to

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileArray2.length; i++)
```

So unless `fileArray1.length == fileArray2.length` you will be reading values you didn't initialise.

I suggest you discard the second array as it doesn't do anything useful and merge the two outer loops, then you would be trying to read something you didn't write.

```
for (String humanStr : file.split("#", 0)) {
    String[] h = humanStr.split("\n", 0);

    madeHumanArrayList.add(new Human(h[0], Integer.parseInt(h[1]), 
                                     Float.parseFloat(h[2]), Float.parseFloat(h[3])));
}
```

Finally, I wouldn't use `float` unless there is a very good reason.  I suggest using `double` or `BigDecimal` instead as these have more precision.